# What's the most cost effective way to build a foley pit?

Tags: foley, foley-artist, building, studio, studio-design

Hey guys I'm looking to start building a decent sized foley pit for my studio and would love to hear from anyone who has done this before. I know it's mostly just squared off blocks of wood with different textures filled inside but I'm wondering what else I could do that would get a lot of use. Let me know if you have had any experience in this thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Planning.  Draw your design get the measurement.  price of wood adds up fast, especially when you buy extra.  it shouldnt cost more then about 300-400 for the wood for an 8foot by 2 foot pit.  not including the tiles, terrain, and whatever else you want to put in the pit.  also a good idea to make it in sections when you can lift a door to get to a tile, that way you have the entire 8x2 top to do footsteps etc if needed.